# determine current process priority from within a running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, nice

I want to ensure a script can only be run below a certain nice level. I searched around and I didn't find a good way of doing this, so I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# use ps to get the niceness of the current process
# only look at the last line of output
# remove whitespace
readonly PRIORITY=$(ps -o '%n' $$ | tail -n 1 | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
if [[ "${PRIORITY}" -lt "10" ]]; then
    exit 100
fi
```

This seems sloppy to me, it would be *nice* if there was a more simple way of doing this. I guess I really just want a tiny program that returns the current process's scheduling priority, but I don't want to write the 3 lines of c code myself :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation of the GNU coreutils `nice` command:

> ```
> Usage: nice [OPTION] [COMMAND [ARG]...]
> ```
>
> Run `COMMAND` with an adjusted niceness, which affects process scheduling.
>   **With no `COMMAND`, print the current niceness.**

However, beware that

> NOTE: your shell may have its own version of nice, which usually supersedes
>   the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation
>   for details about the options it supports.

In case your shell does have such a builtin with different behavior, you'd want to use the usual techniques for running a binary rather than builtin.

Comment: thank you, I will accept this answer as soon as I can